# Error applying suggestionCallback in a closure

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function(text, suggestionsCallback){
    ....
    $.get(url_base + text, function(data){
        ....
        suggestionsCallback(suggest_results);
```

In my callback closure "suggestionCallback" takes no effect.
But if I put this callback line outside of the closure, the line just works fine.

Is this a bug of Chrome? Or, did I miss-understand something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the omnibar api, but you could try adding some console.log statements to see what's going on, or give us more of your code. Literally, it's fine to put a lot of your code in a question.

I highly doubt that it's a bug with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of jquery and am just horrid with details, so I cant explain to you why it doesnt work.  But in my tests I noticed that doing it in a none jquery way works, so try something like this....

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(
function(text, suggest) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url_base + text, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            suggest(suggest_results);
        } else {
            //error, not found or something
            console.debug('Im bugging out man!');
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
});
```